# Why is this std::bind not converted to std::function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, bind

Why is the nested `std::bind` in the below code not implicitly converted to an `std::function<void()>` by any of the major compilers (VS2010/2012, gcc, clang)? Is this standard behavior, or a bug?

```
#include <functional>

void bar(int, std::function<void()>) { }
void foo() { }

int main()
{
    std::function<void(int, std::function<void()>)> func;
    func = std::bind(bar, 5, std::bind(foo));

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because nested bind expressions are eagerly evaluated. In effect you're doing something akin to `std::bind(bar, 5, void)`, which is nonsensical.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but this: `func = std::bind(bar, 5,foo);` works as you expected.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? `bar` can be assigned directly to `func`, by binding the arguments you are creating a functor that can be called with no arguments (or any combination or arguments). With the current code (assuming it compiled) `func` would have to be called with an int and a `std::function<void()>`, both arguments would be ignored and that would trigger the execution of `bar(5,foo)`...

Comment: I realized this example was functionally wrong, but it displayed the compiler error I was asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/bind/bind.html#nested_binds):

> **The inner bind expressions are evaluated, in unspecified order, before
>   the outer bind when the function object is called; the results of the
>   evaluation are then substituted in their place when the outer bind is
>   evaluated**. In the example above, when the function object is called
>   with the argument list (x), bind(g, _1)(x) is evaluated first,
>   yielding g(x), and then bind(f, g(x))(x) is evaluated, yielding the
>   final result f(g(x)).

Boost even provides `protect` to prevent this evaluation:

```
#include <boost/bind/protect.hpp>
...
func = std::bind(bar, 5, boost::protect(std::bind(foo)));
```

However, to call `func` you have to provide both arguments like this (thanks to [David Rodríguez - dribeas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615873/why-is-this-stdbind-not-converted-to-stdfunction/13615974#comment18670863_13615873) for pointing that out), so this example is definitely not good:

```
func(1, std::function<void()>());
```

Comment: Do `boost::protect` and `std::bind` play nicely together? I haven't tried, but I assumed they wouldn't...

Comment: @ildjarn: `boost::protect` is nothing special really, it's just a perfect forwarding functor, if you so will. What's special is `std::bind`'s return type, for which [`std::is_bind_expression`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/is_bind_expression) is true. Depending on that trait, a functor is either eagerly evaluated, or just passed along normally. For the result of `boost::protect`, `is_bind_expression` derives from `false_type`.